# Add Columns Then Separate Data By Category

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have been researching this for a while now and have not found a solid resource for what I want to do.  I currently have a DataTable that is displaying the total amount of hours worked as well as the total hours worked based on a user applied filter (can be date, name, etc.).  What I would like to implement is for the summed totals to breakdown even further to show how many hours are worked by each category.  For instance (using my jsfiddle I made as an example) if you searched for 'engineer' then not only would a total sum appear, but also a sum for each of the office locations (ignore the bullets):

- London:      $295,500
- San Francisco:   $409,350
- Singapore:   $234,500
- Tokyo:       $139,575
- Edinburgh:   $103,600
- New York:    $125,250
- Total Hours: $1,307,775.00

Here is my sum script:

```
"footerCallback": function (row, start, end, display) {
                var api = this.api(),
                    data;

                // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
                var intVal = function (i) {
                    return typeof i === 'string' ?
                        i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
                        typeof i === 'number' ?
                            i : 0;
                };

                // Total over all pages
                total = api
                    .column(5)
                    .data()
                    .reduce(function (a, b) {
                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                    }, 0);

                // Total over all filtered pages
                if (api.column(5, {
                    search: 'applied'
                }).data().length) {
                    pageTotal = api
                        .column(5, {
                            search: 'applied'
                        })
                        .data()
                        .reduce(function (a, b) {
                            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                        });
                } else {
                    pageTotal = 0;
                }

                $(api.column(5).footer()).html(
                    pageTotal.toFixed(2)
                );

                // Update footer
                $(api.column(5).footer()).html(
                    pageTotal.toFixed(2) + ' hours ( ' + total.toFixed(2) + ' total hours)'
                );
```

Here is a link to my jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/hfyo90w7/

I would like the categories to be dynamic and not hard coded because I am sure that for the program I am making they will be subject to change as time goes on.  I would greatly appreciate any help on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to reduce all the row data and extract the common values to use as object keys. This is a very common `groupBy` pattern

Example for summing salaries by office:

```
  var byOffice = api.rows().data().reduce(function(a, c) {
        a[c[2]] = a[c[2]] || 0;
        a[c[2]] += intVal(c[5]);
      return a
    }, {});
```

This returns an object with office names as keys and sum of salaries as values.

Then iterate that object to create whatever html you need

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hfyo90w7/28/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for this.  I'll look into this and see what I can do.

Comment: I can't seem to get the data to display properly.  I keep getting the [object Object] error to display.  What is the proper way of grabbing the data and showing it in html?

Comment: If you use `Object.entries(byOffice)` will get array where first element is office, second is the value

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you very much.